# Mapping pnbinom() in R to scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(k, n, p, loc=0) in SciPy

Tags: python, r, scipy, data-science, binomial-coefficients

I am having hard time to understand how the [`pnbinom(q, size, prob, mu, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)` in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) to the [scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf(k, n, p, loc=0) in SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html).

For the R function, the definitions of the parameters are as follows.

```
q   =vector of quantiles.

size    = target for number of successful trials, or dispersion parameter (the shape parameter of the gamma mixing distribution). Must be strictly positive, need not be integer.

prob    =probability of success in each trial. 0 < prob <= 1.

mu  = alternative parametrization via mean: see ‘Details’.

log, log.p  =logical; if TRUE, probabilities p are given as log(p).

lower.tail =    logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].
```

For the SciPy function, the parameters are defined as follows.

```
 n is the    number of successes
 p is the probability of a single success.
```

For example, if

```
k=20

a=1.2

p=0.1
```

In R, `pnbinom(k,a,p) =  0.8518848`. Here, `k` is plugged into `q` i.e. the vector of quantiles, `a` is plugged into `size`, and `p` is plugged into 'prob'.

On the other hand, in SciPy, I assumed `n` is what used as `size` and `p` is what we used as `prob` in R. In that setting, `nbinom.pmf(k, a, p) = 0.01530062999480606`.

Could anyone please help to identify what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nbinom.pmf(k, a, p)` returns the pmf (probability mass function), while `pnbinom(k, a, p)` is the cdf (cumulative distribution function).

Try `nbinom.cdf(k, a, p)` to get the cdf from scipy, or `dnbinom(k, a, p)` to get the pmf in R.